# I need re run project for loading images

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

I have a problem when I add new product create a folder and add images to there but images won't load. I need to re run project then images will load

Here is my html and jstl code

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <a href="detail?id=${product.id}">
          <img src="${product.image}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <a href="detail?id=${product.id}">
          <img src="${product.image}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="adetail.html" class="invisible">
    <img src="${product.image}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <div class="text">
    <h3><a href="adetail.html" id="productName">${product.name}</a></h3>
    <p class="price">${product.price} AZN</p>
    <p class="buttons">
      <a href="detail?id=${product.id}" class="btn btn-default" class="prDetail">View detail</a>
      <a href="detail?id=${product.id}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.text -->
</div>
```

and database code also

```
@Override
public List<Product> listProducts(int catId, int parentID) {
    List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, price, image FROM products WHERE categoryid = ? AND parentid = ? LIMIT 8");
        ps.setInt(1, catId);
        ps.setInt(2, parentID);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            p.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            p.setImage("img/" + p.getId() + "/" + rs.getString("image"));
            p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));

            list.add(p);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        close(conn);
        close(ps);
        close(rs);
    }
    return list;
}
```

add product controlle code is here. I created temp folder add images there then get product id from db and rename temp to that id

```
    Gson imgs = new Gson();
    Product p = new Product();

    String name = null;
    String image = null;
    String pImages;
    String descAz = null;
    String descRu = null;

    double discount = 0;

    String jsonToString = "";

    int count = 0;
    int categoryId = 0;
    int prentId = 0;
    long id;
    double price = 0;

    try {
        String filePathOld = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Project\\ProjectName\\web\\img\\";
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Project\\ProjectName\\web\\img\\temp\\";
        String fileName;
        File f = new File(filePath);
        f.mkdir();
        boolean isMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
        if (!isMultiPart) {
            return;
        }

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        List<FileItem> files = upload.parseRequest(req);
        List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FileItem item : files) {

            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                fileName = item.getName();
                if (!item.getFieldName().equals("mainImg")) {
                    item.write(new File(filePath + fileName));
                    images.add(fileName);
                } else {

                    p.setImage(fileName);

                    item.write(new File(filePath + fileName));
                }
            } else {
                if (item.getFieldName().equals("pName")) {
                    name = item.getString("UTF-8");
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("pPrice")) {
                    price = Double.parseDouble(item.getString("UTF-8"));
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("pCount")) {
                    count = Integer.parseInt(item.getString("UTF-8"));
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("selectedCat")) {
                    categoryId = Integer.parseInt(item.getString("UTF-8"));
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("discount")) {
                    discount = Double.parseDouble(item.getString("UTF-8"));
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("selectedSubCat")) {
                    prentId = Integer.parseInt(item.getString("UTF-8"));
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("descAz")) {
                    descAz = item.getString("UTF-8");
                } else if (item.getFieldName().equals("descRu")) {
                    descRu = item.getString("UTF-8");
                }
            }
        }

        Image img = new Image();
        img.setName(images);

        p.setName(name);
        p.setCount(count);
        p.setPrice(price);
        p.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        p.setPrentId(prentId);
        p.setDescAz(descAz);
        p.setDescRu(descRu);
        p.setDiscount(discount);

        jsonToString = imgs.toJson(img);

        int pid = db.addProduct(p, jsonToString);
        File newN = new File(filePathOld + "\\" + pid);
        f.renameTo(newN);

    } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

select product database code

```
 List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, price, image FROM products WHERE categoryid = ? AND parentid = ? LIMIT 8");
        ps.setInt(1, catId);
        ps.setInt(2, parentID);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            p.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            p.setImage("img\\" + p.getId() + "\\" + rs.getString("image"));
            p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));

            list.add(p);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        close(conn);
        close(ps);
        close(rs);
    }
    return list;
```

add product method code

```
int pId = 0;
    try {

        conn = ds.getConnection();

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO products VALUES(0,?,?,?,?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, p.getName());
        ps.setDouble(2, p.getPrice());
        ps.setString(3, p.getImage());
        ps.setDouble(4, p.getDiscount());
        ps.setInt(5, p.getCategoryId());
        ps.setInt(6, p.getPrentId());

        ps.executeUpdate();

        rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()) {
            pId = rs.getInt(1);
        }

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product_detail VALUES(0,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1, pId);
        ps.setString(2, jsonImage);
        ps.setInt(3, p.getCount());
        ps.setString(4, p.getDescAz());
        ps.setString(5, p.getDescRu());

        ps.executeUpdate();

        conn.commit();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    } finally {
        close(conn);
        close(ps);
        close(rs);
    }
    return pId;
```

Comment: it's maybe because of the browser's cache ! so check out if the cache is disable!

Comment: @AtimeneNazim thanks for your answer but it didint help. i also add controller code also thanks for editing answer :)

Comment: When you add the images, can you see them on database ? can you show us how do you add images ?

Comment: Yes, folder also created and images added to that path but images seen at the view only after re run project i edited question and added controller at the database only save image name when select image do it like that -> p.setImage("img\\" + p.getId() + "\\" + rs.getString("image"));

Comment: @AtimeneNazim i also added database select code

Comment: Did you try to clean the session after adding images ?

Comment: @AtimeneNazim sorry but, how could i do it ?

Comment: where is you `addProduct()` methode ?

Comment: it is a database method and called in controller which i shared . Now added add product methode also

Comment: Try to replace `close(conn)` and the others by  `rs.close() ;ps.close(); conn.close(); ` in the order.

Comment: Sorry but it did not helped